# Filtro en carga de Datos

Tags: php, html, ajax, mysqli

Tengo una salida de datos en pantalla en donde se cargan los datos de una tabla en este caso seria de la tabla programas y que actualmente se ve de la siguiente manera:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Esta pantalla la estoy pintando con el siguiente código

```html
<?php
include "../config/config.php"; //Contiene funcion que conecta a la base de datos

$action = (isset($_REQUEST['action']) && $_REQUEST['action'] != NULL) ? $_REQUEST['action'] : '';
?>

  <?php
if ($action == 'ajax') {
    // escapando, eliminando además todo lo que podría ser (html/javascript-) code
    $q = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, (strip_tags($_REQUEST['q'], ENT_QUOTES)));
    $aColumns = array('nombre', 'id_sub_categoria', 'descripcion_producto', 'acciones', 'impedimento'); //Columnas de busqueda
    $sTable = "programas";
    $sWhere = "";

    if ($_GET['q'] != "") {
        $sWhere = "WHERE id_sub_categoria = 1 AND (";
        for ($i = 0; $i < count($aColumns); $i++) {
            $sWhere .= $aColumns[$i] . " LIKE '%" . $q . "%' OR ";
        }
        $sWhere = substr_replace($sWhere, "", -3);
        $sWhere .= ')';
    }

    $sWhere .= "ORDER BY id_institucion, nombre ASC";
    include 'pagination.php'; //include pagination file
    //pagination variables
    $page = (isset($_REQUEST['page']) && !empty($_REQUEST['page'])) ? $_REQUEST['page'] : 1;
    $per_page = 10; //how much records you want to show
    $adjacents = 4; //gap between pages after number of adjacents
    $offset = ($page - 1) * $per_page;
    //Count the total number of row in your table*/
    $count_query = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT count(*) AS numrows FROM $sTable  $sWhere");
    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($count_query);
    $numrows = $row['numrows'];
    $total_pages = ceil($numrows / $per_page);
    $reload = './programa_capacitacion.php';
    //main query to fetch the data
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM  $sTable $sWhere LIMIT $offset,$per_page";
    $query = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
    //loop through fetched data
    if ($numrows > 0) {
        ?>
    <table class="table table-striped jambo_table bulk_action">
      <thead>
        <tr class="headings">
          <th class="column-title">Programa </th>
          <th class="column-title">Institución</th>
          <th class="column-title">Estado </th>
          <th class="column-title no-link last"><span class="nobr"></span></th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <?php
                foreach ($query as $key => $r) {
                    $id = $r['id'];
                    $id_institucion = $r['id_institucion'];
                    $id_sede = $r['id_sede'];
                    $id_sector = $r['id_sector'];
                    $id_tipo_fondo = $r['id_tipo_fondo'];
                    $id_modalidad = $r['id_modalidad'];
                    $nombre = $r['nombre'];
                    $id_encargado = $r['id_encargado'];
                    $descripcion = $r['descripcion'];
                    $id_categoria = $r['id_categoria'];
                    $id_sub_categoria = $r['id_sub_categoria'];
                    $id_publico_meta = $r['id_publico_meta'];
                    $boton_ano = $r['duracion_anos'];
                    $boton_mes = $r['duracion_meses'];
                    $boton_dia = $r['duracion_dias'];
                    $boton_hora = $r['duracion_horas'];
                    $id_costo_servicio = $r['id_costo_servicio'];
                    $id_cobertura_servicio = $r['id_cobertura_servicio'];
                    $id_ciclo_vida = $r['id_ciclo_vida'];
                    $id_tema = $r['id_tema'];
                    $requisito = $r['requisito'];
                    $condicion_credito = $r['condicion_credito'];
                    $descripcion_producto = $r['descripcion_producto'];
                    $saldo_ano_anterior = $r['saldo_ano_anterior'];
                    $observaciones_ano_anterior = $r['observaciones_ano_anterior'];
                    $saldo_ano_posterior = $r['saldo_ano_posterior'];
                    $observaciones_ano_posterior = $r['observaciones_ano_posterior'];
                    $marco_normativo = $r['marco_normativo'];
                    $impedimento = $r['impedimento'];
                    $acciones = $r['acciones'];
                    $fecha_registro = date('d/m/Y h:i', strtotime($r['fecha_registro']));
                    $id_usuario_crea = $r['id_usuario_crea'];
                    $fecha_update = date('d/m/Y h:i', strtotime($r['fecha_update']));
                    $id_usuario_update = $r['id_usuario_update'];
                    $active = $r['active'];

                    $sql = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE id=$id_usuario_crea");

                    if ($c = mysqli_fetch_array($sql)) {
                        $name_user = $c['nombre'];
                    }

                    $sql = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM instituciones WHERE id=$id_institucion");

                    if ($c = mysqli_fetch_array($sql)) {
                        $institucion = $c['nombre'];
                    }

                    $sql = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM sedes WHERE id=$id_sede");

                    if ($c = mysqli_fetch_array($sql)) {
                        $nombre_sede = $c['nombre'];
                    }

                    $sql = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM tipos_fondos WHERE id=$id_tipo_fondo");

                    if ($c = mysqli_fetch_array($sql)) {
                        $tipo_fondo = $c['nombre'];
                    }

                    $sql = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM modalidades WHERE id=$id_modalidad");

                    if ($id_modalidad != null) {
                        if ($c = mysqli_fetch_array($sql)) {
                            $modalidad = $c['nombre'];
                        }
                    } else {
                        $modalidad = 'No Indica';
                    }

                    $sql = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM categorias WHERE id=$id_categoria");

                    if ($c = mysqli_fetch_array($sql)) {
                        $categoria = $c['nombre'];
                    }

                    $sql = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM sub_categorias WHERE id=$id_sub_categoria");

                    if ($c = mysqli_fetch_array($sql)) {
                        $sub_categoria = $c['nombre'];
                    }

                    $sql = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM publico_meta WHERE id=$id_publico_meta");

                    if ($c = mysqli_fetch_array($sql)) {
                        $publico_meta = $c['nombre'];
                    }

                    $sql = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM costos_servicios WHERE id=$id_costo_servicio");

                    if ($c = mysqli_fetch_array($sql)) {
                        $costo_servicio = $c['nombre'];
                    }

                    $sql = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM cobertura_servicios WHERE id=$id_cobertura_servicio");

                    if ($c = mysqli_fetch_array($sql)) {
                        $cobertura_servicio = $c['nombre'];
                    }

                    $sql = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM ciclo_vida WHERE id=$id_ciclo_vida");

                    if ($id_ciclo_vida != null) {
                        if ($c = mysqli_fetch_array($sql)) {
                            $ciclo_vida = $c['nombre'];
                        }
                    } else {
                        $ciclo_vida = 'No indica';
                    }

                    $sql = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM temas WHERE id=$id_tema");

                    if ($c = mysqli_fetch_array($sql)) {
                        $tema = $c['nombre'];
                    }

                    $sql = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM encargados_programas WHERE id=$id_encargado");

                    if ($c = mysqli_fetch_array($sql)) {
                        $encargado = $c['nombre'];
                    }

                    if ($condicion_credito != null) {
                        $credito = $condicion_credito;
                    } else {
                        $credito = 'No Indica';
                    }

                    if ($saldo_ano_anterior != null) {
                        $saldo_anterior = $saldo_ano_anterior;
                    } else {
                        $saldo_anterior = 'No Indica';
                    }

                    if ($observaciones_ano_anterior != null) {
                        $observaciones_anterior = $observaciones_ano_anterior;
                    } else {
                        $observaciones_anterior = 'No Indica';
                    }

                    if ($observaciones_ano_posterior != null) {
                        $observaciones_posterior = $observaciones_ano_posterior;
                    } else {
                        $observaciones_posterior = 'No Indica';
                    }

                    if ($saldo_ano_posterior != null) {
                        $saldo_posterior = $saldo_ano_posterior;
                    } else {
                        $saldo_posterior = 'No Indica';
                    }

                    if (isset($active) && $active == 1) {
                        $is_active = "Activo";
                    } elseif (isset($active) && $active == 0) {
                        $is_active = "Inactivo";
                    }
                    ?>

          <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $id; ?>" id="id<?php echo $id; ?>">
          <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $id_institucion; ?>" id="id_institucion<?php echo $id; ?>">
          <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $id_sede; ?>" id="id_sede<?php echo $id; ?>">
          <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $id_sector; ?>" id="id_sector<?php echo $id; ?>">
          <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $id_tipo_fondo; ?>" id="id_tipo_fondo<?php echo $id; ?>">
          <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $id_modalidad; ?>" id="id_modalidad<?php echo $id; ?>">
          <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $nombre; ?>" id="nombre<?php echo $id; ?>">
          <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $id_encargado; ?>" id="id_encargado<?php echo $id; ?>">
          <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $descripcion; ?>" id="descripcion<?php echo $id; ?>">
          <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $id_categoria; ?>" id="id_categoria<?php echo $id; ?>">
          <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $id_sub_categoria; ?>" id="id_sub_categoria<?php echo $id; ?>">
          <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $id_publico_meta; ?>" id="id_publico_meta<?php echo $id; ?>">
          <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $boton_ano; ?>" id="boton_ano<?php echo $id; ?>">
          <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $boton_mes; ?>" id="boton_mes<?php echo $id; ?>">
          <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $boton_dia; ?>" id="boton_dia<?php echo $id; ?>">
          <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $boton_hora; ?>" id="boton_hora<?php echo $id; ?>">
          <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $id_costo_servicio; ?>" id="id_costo_servicio<?php echo $id; ?>">
          <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $id_cobertura_servicio; ?>" id="id_cobertura_servicio<?php echo $id; ?>">
          <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $id_ciclo_vida; ?>" id="id_ciclo_vida<?php echo $id; ?>">
          <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $id_tema; ?>" id="id_tema<?php echo $id; ?>">
          <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $requisito; ?>" id="requisito<?php echo $id; ?>">
          <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $condicion_credito; ?>" id="condicion_credito<?php echo $id; ?>">
          <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $descripcion_producto; ?>" id="descripcion_producto<?php echo $id; ?>">
          <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $saldo_ano_anterior; ?>" id="saldo_ano_anterior<?php echo $id; ?>">
          <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $observaciones_ano_anterior; ?>" id="observaciones_ano_anterior<?php echo $id; ?>">
          <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $saldo_ano_posterior; ?>" id="saldo_ano_posterior<?php echo $id; ?>">
          <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $observaciones_ano_posterior; ?>" id="observaciones_ano_posterior<?php echo $id; ?>">
          <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $marco_normativo; ?>" id="marco_normativo<?php echo $id; ?>">
          <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $impedimento; ?>" id="impedimento<?php echo $id; ?>">
          <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $acciones; ?>" id="acciones<?php echo $id; ?>">
          <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $fecha_registro; ?>" id="fecha_registro<?php echo $id; ?>">
          <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $id_usuario_crea; ?>" id="id_usuario_crea<?php echo $id; ?>">
          <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $fecha_update; ?>" id="fecha_update<?php echo $id; ?>">
          <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $id_usuario_update; ?>" id="id_usuario_update<?php echo $id; ?>">
          <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $active; ?>" id="active<?php echo $id; ?>">

          <tr class="even pointer">

            <td>
              <?php echo $nombre ?>
            </td>
            <td>
              <?php echo $institucion ?>
            </td>
            <td>
              <?php echo $is_active; ?>
            </td>

            <td style="width: auto"><span class="pull-right">
                            <a href="#" class='btn btn-default' title='Ver Programa' onclick="menu1(obtener_datos('<?php echo $id; ?>'));" data-toggle="modal" data-target=".bs-example-modal-lg-udp"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open"></i></a>                             
                </tr>
                <?php
            } //end while
            ?>
            <tr>
                <td colspan=6><span class="pull-right">
                        <?php echo paginate($reload, $page, $total_pages, $adjacents); ?>
                    </span></td>
          </tr>
    </table>
    </div>
    <?php
    } else {
        ?>
      <div class="alert alert-warning alert-dismissible" role="alert">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <strong>Aviso!</strong> No hay datos para mostrar
      </div>
      <?php
    }
}
?>
```

Y realmente si tuviera que traerme todos los datos de la tabla, lo esta haciendo bien, el asunto es que deberia estar cargando solo 1 linea que son los programas de capacitacion, en otras palabras de todas esas lineas realmente deberia mostrarme solo una que es la que tiene un id_sub_categoria = 1, que son capacitaciones nada mas, pero me carga todos los campos sin aplicar el WHERE

Comment: En tu código hay varios condicionales, entonces depura para verificar por dónde está pasando el código para determinar a qué se debe que no está aplicando el filtro esperado.

Comment: Listo, agregar $sWhere = "WHERE id_sub_categoria = 1 ";   antes de $sWhere .= "ORDER BY id_institucion, nombre ASC";